# jexcel generating error on creating file

Tags: jexcelapi

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");
//InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
```

its now working this way
 JExcel to write to Excel Worksheets with my Java Application.

How can I export data from an array to an Excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to  write the output to a file
i think it may work in case of writing to the file

```
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
    // new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```